# Retrofit2で動的なJsonフォーマットに対応する方法

Tags: android, java, retrofit

Retrofit2を使ってGitHub APIを叩くアプリケーションを作成しているのですが,  
例えば[Event API](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/#events)の場合, `type`フィールドの値によって後続の `payload`の中身が決定されます.

`type`が`"PushEvent"`であれば...

```
"payload": {
    "push_id": xxxx,
    "size": 1,
    "distinct_size": 1,
    "ref": "refs/heads/master",
    "head": "aaaa",
    "before": "bbbb",
    "commits": [
        {
          "sha": "aaaa",
          "author": {
              "email": "hoge",
              "name": "hoge"
          },
          "message": "xxx",
          "distinct": true,
          "url": "xxx"
        }
    ]
},
```

`type`が`"PullRequestEvent"`であれば...

```
"payload": {
    "action": "opened",
    "number": 1,
    "pull_request": {
        "url": "xxx",
        "id": 0000,
        "html_url": "xxx",
        "diff_url": "xxx",
        "patch_url": "xxx",
        "issue_url": "xxx",
        "number": 0,
        "state": "open",
        "locked": false,
        "title": "xxx",
        ...
```

といった具合です.

上記のケースにおいて, レスポンスの中身を見て`AbstractEvent`の具象クラス(例えば`PushEvent`や`PullRequestEvent`)を生成する方法も考えられますが,  
これをRetrofit2で実現する場合のベストプラクティスを模索しています.

例えば下記の`GET API`を定義しておき,

```
@GET("/users/{username}/events/public")
Observable<List<AbstractEvent>> listEvent(@Path("username") String username);
```

`Custom Converter`の機能を使って`PushEvent`オブジェクトや`PullRequestEvent`オブジェクトを生成する方法が妥当なのでしょうか？  
こういったケースでのRetrofit2の作法をご教授いただけると幸いです.

---

**追記 : 2016.04.08**

(一部自己解決しました)
現状、上記のケースでは下記の実装方法がしっくりきました.

`Events`の`Type`と`Json`変換後の`VO`を持つ`Enum`を定義.

```
public enum EventType {
    @SerializedName("PullRequestEvent")
    PullRequestEvent(PullRequestEvent.class),
    @SerializedName("PushEvent")
    PushEvent(PushEvent.class),

    private Type type;

    EventType(Type type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Type getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

自前の`JsonDeserializer`を用意.  
`payload`の中身を引数に先ほどの`Enum`から`VO`を導出しパースする.

```
public static class EventDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Event> {

    @Override
    public Event deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        Event message = new Gson().fromJson(jsonElement, Event.class);
        if (message == null) {
            return null;
        }

        EventType eventType = message.getType();
        JsonElement data = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("payload");
        if (eventType == null || data == null) {
            message.payload = null;
            return message;
        }

        message.payload = new Gson().fromJson(data, eventType.getType());
        return message;
    }
}
```

`Retrofit`には`TypeAdapter`を設定.

```
protected GitHubApi createGitHubApi() {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(Event.class, new Event.EventDeserializer())
            .create();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(GitHubApi.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();
    return retrofit.create(GitHubApi.class);
}
```

[GitHub.java](https://github.com/YukiMatsumura/HusaHusa/blob/master/app/src/main/java/yuki/m/android/husahusa/data/GitHub.java)